# Black screen on xubuntu 16.10

Tags: xubuntu, 16.10, amd-graphics

So I upgraded Xubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, and when I restarted I got a black screen. I thought it might be to do with my graphics card, so I set my motherboard to force CPU graphics and booted in. Now I can see my login screen, but my keyboard and mouse won't do anything. I have an AMD R9 390 if that helps.